# <p> tag the_content()

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to configure my content-page.php but i'm struggling with a few 'mistakes'.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="page_content">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
**<p class="page_tekst">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</p>**
</div>
</article>
```

This is my css content

```
.page_content
{
    width:820px;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.page_tekst
{
    text-align:justify;
    float:left;
}
```

This is the result in my browser

```
<article id="post-81">
<div class="page_content">
<h1>test</h1>
<p class="page_tekst">
<p>This is a test based on the current css code</p>
</p>
</article>
```

My css on the .page_tekst won't work. I also understand why but is there a solution for it? Can you make a div or p tag, give it a call and put the content in this tag without making another P tag with the content?

Comment: P elements are not block elements, you should not be nesting them as the browser will correct the issue by separating them out into multiple elements. use a div or some other block element rather than an inline element such as a p tag

Answer (score 1):

WordPress inserts p tags in `the_content()`, otherwise it would be rather difficult for your content to contain more than one paragraph. If you want to target the p WordPress inserts, just change your css to:

```
.page_content p
{
    text-align:justify;
    float:left;
}
```

and remove your wrapping `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What i'm trying to reach is to add some text together with a featured image. The image must 'wrap' around the text. But with your answer in my head, I think this is fully possible. Isn't it? Thanks!